# Python: Fastest way of parsing first column of large table in array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, csv

So I have got two very big tables that I would like to compare (9 columns and approx 30 million rows).

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import csv


def compare(sam1, sam2, output):
    with open(sam1, "r") as s1, open(sam2, "r") as s2, open(output, "w") as out:
    reader1 = csv.reader(s1, delimiter = "\t")
    reader2 = csv.reader(s2, delimiter = "\t")
    writer  = csv.writer(out, delimiter = "\t")
    list = []
    for line in reader1:
        list.append(line[0])
    list = set(list)

    for line in reader2:
        for field in line:
            if field not in list:
                writer.writerow(line)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    compare(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])
```

The first column contains the identifier of my rows and I would like to know which ones are only in sam1.

So this is the code I am currently working with, but it takes ages. Is there any way to speed it up?

I already tried to speed it up by converting the list to a set, but there was no big difference.

Edit: Now it is running much quicker but now I have to get the whole lines out of my input table and write the lines with exclusive ID to the output file. How could I manage this in a quick way?

Comment: Just a top level idea, quickly read through the files to create two sets containing first row of each file. Find (setA - setB) to get the rows which are present only in setA

Comment: I thought about this but I could not figure out how to realise it in a fast manner.

Comment: You have to read the whole files anyways. Using set rather than list simply makes it a little faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few suggestions:

- Rather than creating a list that you then turn into a set, just work with a set directly:

  ```
  sam1_identifiers = set()
  for line in reader1:
      sam1_identifiers.add(line[0])
  ```

  This is probably more memory efficient, because you have a single set rather than a list and a set. That might make it a bit faster.

  Note also that I've changed the variable name – `list` is the name of a Python builtin function, so you shouldn't use it for your own variables.
- Since you want to find the identifiers which are only in sam1, rather than the nested if/for statements, just compare and throw away any identifiers found in sam2 that are in the set of IDs in sam1.

  ```
  sam2_identifiers = set()
  for line in reader2:
      sam2_identifiers.add(line[0])

  print sam1 - sam2
  ```

  or even

  ```
  sam2_identifiers = set()
  for line in reader2:
      sam1_identifiers.discard(line[0])

  print sam1_identifiers
  ```

  I suspect that's faster than the nested loops.
- Perhaps I've missed something, but don't you look through every column for each line of sam2? Isn't it sufficient just to look at `line[0]` for the identifier, as with sam1?

Comment: No, you are right it is sufficient to look at `line[0]` there as well.

Comment: Please take a look at my question I added an additional question.